# how to create a INSTEAD OF DELETE

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that delete row from [t_Supporter] when a row from t_user is deleted and before delete row of [t_Supporter] update row from t_ticket .

```
create trigger [dbo].[deleteUser]
on [dbo].[t_user]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
as
BEGIN 
  delete from  [dbo].[t_Supporter]
    where EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM deleted 
          WHERE  deleted.userID  = [t_Supporter].userID_FK  )

   DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_user]
     where EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM deleted 
          WHERE  deleted.userID  = [t_user].userID  )
END

create TRIGGER [dbo].[supporterDelete]
ON [dbo].[t_Supporter]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
 update t_ticket 
   set supporterID_FK = null,supDelete = 1
     where EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM deleted 
          WHERE  deleted.userID_FK  = t_ticket.supporterID_FK )  

 DELETE FROM [dbo].[t_Supporter]
 where EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM deleted 
          WHERE  deleted.supporterID  = [t_Supporter].supporterID  )
END
```

but when i delete from t_user , i get this error:

[image]

Comment: If your delete process really needs such triggering around, I would rather use a Stored Procedure "DeleteUser" in which you do the tricky work in one go. To ensure this approach, you could use instead of triggers to avoid wrong deletions. Your SP would disable these triggers in the beginning and enable them as last action.

Comment: I soved it, instead of deleted.userID  = [t_Supporter].userID_FK , I use deleted.supporterID  = t_ticket.supporterID_FK

Comment: One more thing to think about: There are really few scenarios where you should physically delete data. Better mark them as "deleted". This way allows you to write beside who and when deleted this. You could have archiving routines (with physical clean up) in bigger periodes.

Comment: It looks like you've got a clash with a foreign key constraint where the supporter table you are trying to delete from is referenced by another table (maybe ticket). It would be necessary to rework the tables so that the supporter table (or some sort of copy of it) was not being referenced by anything else in order to prevent the foreign key constraint from complaining about the deletion.

Comment: Another way to solve this is to make sure when you are deleting 1's out of the supporter table you would need to take the 1's out of any table that references it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly saying cause of the error.

> you can't delete a given parent row if a child row exists that
>   references the value for that parent row. If the parent row has no
>   referencing child rows, then you can delete that parent row.this is
>   the default behavior for a foreign key.

you can't delete record from the table if you refer it's value to the another(Foreign_Key) table and if reference table got any value then you'll get the error on delete.

so, you have to delete record from the child table(foreign_key) first and then you'll be able to delete record from the main table.

Comment: This is not an answer... Your own part is not more than a (quite obvious) comment, your second part is a copy of my comment...

Comment: may be, but i already define the cause of the error.
it'll help the user to know why getting the error. @Shnugo